# Как добавить анимацию когда состояние блока меняется на display: none?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите как добавить сюда анимацию, чтобы при нажатию на кнопку блок плавно выдвигался, и если нажать еще раз кнопку, чтобы блок плавно прятался.
 Знаю, что можно воспользоваться например методом .toggle("slow"), но мне обязательно нужно использовать toggleClass

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".hideList").click(function(){
      $(this).prev('table').find('tr:nth-child(n+4)').toggleClass("hidden");
    })

});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
th, td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

.button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem1</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem2</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem3</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem4</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem5</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem6</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>lorem1</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem2</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem3</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Hide" class="button hideList"/>





</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще для таблицы не очень удобно делать transition, вот примерно, что можно сделать:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".hideList").click(function(){
      $(this).prev('table').find('tr:nth-child(n+4)').toggleClass("hidden");
    })

});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}
th, td {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}

.button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
/* нужно убрать всё, что влияет на высоту td */
.hidden td{
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem1</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem2</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem3</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem4</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem5</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem6</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>lorem1</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem2</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>lorem3</td>
    <td>lorem</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Hide" class="button hideList"/>





</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Поставьте transition для tr и меняйте его visibility и opacity.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hideList").click(function() {
    $(this).prev('table').find('tr:nth-child(n+4)').toggleClass("hidden");
  })

});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr {
  transition: all 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}

.button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem1</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem2</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem3</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem4</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem5</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem6</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem1</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem2</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>lorem3</td>
      <td>lorem</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" value="Hide" class="button hideList" />





</div>
```

```
input {
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

Comment: transition не работает для display.

Comment: тогда таблица не будет сворачиваться :) на самом деле тут надо отказаться от таблицы и перейти например на flexboxes, но это все равно не решит проблему нормально, т.к. выглядеть будет все равно как "каждая строчка уменьшается сама по себе" (типа как у меня, можно ещё побороться с размером шрифта). самый правильный вариант - просто уменьшить размер контейнера таблицы, но тогда надо вычислить уменьшенный размер исходя из координат и размеров ячейки, хотя, можно схитрить и уменьшить таблицу без перерендеринга, потом задать размер контейнеру и вернуть таблице размер обратно)